# HOW to Deserialize a JSON in ListView C# XAML XAMARIN

Tags: c#, json, xaml, listview, xamarin

I'm trying to download date from a json and put it in a list view but i don't know how to do it.
From my YRL, using postman, I download these info:

> {"users":[{"email":"ciccio@libero.it","nickname":"Franco","image":"http://localhost/MyWebService/images/"},{"email":"email@test.it","nickname":"nickname","image":"http://localhost/MyWebService/images/test_img.png"},{"email":"provoo@controllo.it","nickname":"farfallo","image":"http://localhost/MyWebService/images/"}]}

Now to download this information into my app I have created these classes:

```
public class Users
    {
        [JsonProperty("users", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public User[] UsersUsers { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        [JsonProperty("email", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string email { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("nickname", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string nickname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("password", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string password { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("image", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public Uri image { get; set; }
    }
```

on my XAML page I wrote this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ContentPage
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="TestLoginURL.View.HomePage">
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <StackLayout>
            <Label Text="HomePage"></Label>
            <ListView x:Name="ListViewUsers" RowHeight="60">  
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
                    <DataTemplate>  
                        <ViewCell>  
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="8,0,8,0">
                                <Image Source="{Binding image}" />
                                <Label Text="{Binding nickname}" />  
                                <Label Text="{Binding email}" />  
                            </StackLayout>  
                        </ViewCell>  
                    </DataTemplate>  
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>  
            </ListView>  
        </StackLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

And inside the .cs file I wrote these things:

```
public partial class HomePage : ContentPage
    {

        public HomePage(Model.Users users)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            LoadData();
        }

        public async void LoadData()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            var url = "http://192.168.178.77/TestLoginURL/api/getAllUsers.php";
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url);
            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            var usersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Users>>(content);
            ListViewUsers.ItemsSource = usersList;
        }
    }
```

but unfortunately, the moment I go to open this page, this error appears and the application goes into crush:

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[TestLoginURL.Model.Users]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path 'users', line 1, position 9.

So... can anyone tell me where I'm wrong in the deserialization of the JSON and what the correct code would be?
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare a list of users, check the following:

```
public class User
{
    [JsonProperty("email", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("nickname", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string nickname { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public string password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("image", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public sring image { get; set; }
}


public class YourUsersData
{
  [JsonProperty("users", NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
    public List<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

And then in the code-behind:

```
 var usersList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourUsersData>(content);
 ListViewUsers.ItemsSource = YourUsersData.Users;
```

Comment: Thanks it's work :D 
just change 
ListViewUsers.ItemsSource = YourUsersData.Users; 
in
ListViewUsers.ItemsSource = usersList.Users;

Comment: The only thing that does not work now is that the image does not appear : /

Comment: IS it a url? Check the url, or change the image type object to Uri

Comment: yes but the problem was with the webservice that gave me a wrong url, thank you now everything is ok :)